# mysql C++ connector [mysql-connector-c++-8.0.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit]

Tags: c++, mysql

**My application crashes:**

```
static sql::Driver *driver=get_driver_instance();
shared_ptr<sql::Connection> con(driver->connect("127.0.0.1:3306","asif", "password"));
con->setSchema("asif");  //it crashes here (segv)
```

The code is straight from the sample provided on mysql C++ connector related site

I have the schema **asif**

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| CREBACO            |
| asif               |
| asif1              |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| test               |
+--------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use asif;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_asif |
+----------------+
| tab1           |
| tab2           |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

on debugging:

```
#0  __memmove_sse2_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:371
#1  0x00007ffff7301c80 in std::string::append(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7634efe in sql::SQLString::append (str=..., this=0x7fffffffdc10)
    at /export/home/pb2/build/sb_0-32258110-1547655664.03/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.12/cppconn/sqlstring.h:155
#3  sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection::setSchema (this=0x55555578bed0, catalog=...)
    at /export/home/pb2/build/sb_0-32258110-1547655664.03/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.12/driver/mysql_connection.cpp:1345
#4  0x000055555555585d in main () at ../Crebaco/main.cpp:25
```

call stack from GDB , I get the same error with mysql-connector-c++-1.1.12

Comment: You are most likely not able to connect to the database. Check username, password and so on.

Comment: Hi,I have connected to the database, con(driver->connect("127.0.0.1:3306","asif", "password")); goes through, it fails when I call "setschema". If I give incorrect password, it correctly tells me so.

Comment: What does your debugger say? How does `con` look like? You could for example get a segv in case `con` would be `NULL`

Comment: I checked, it is not null, I have redited the post to place the stack unwind.

Answer (score 0):

the code is pretty simple (This is not the answer), could you try this code to connect to your instance of MYSQL

```
//export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/asif/Desktop/QT/Crebaco/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit/lib64

#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using namespace std;

#define SERVERSTRING "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306"
#define USER "root"
#define PASSWORD "password"
#define DATABASE "test"

int main()
{
    cout<<"Content-Type: application/txt\r\n\r\n";

    try {
      static sql::Driver *driver=get_driver_instance();
      shared_ptr<sql::Connection> con(driver->connect("127.0.0.1:3306","asif", "password"));
      con->setSchema("asif");

      shared_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(con->createStatement());
      shared_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res(stmt->executeQuery("select * from tab1"));

      while (res->next()) {
          cout << res->getString("name") << endl;
      }

    }catch(sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what()<<endl;
        cout << "MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode()<<endl;
          //cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState()<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```